# No redirecting when id does not exist in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For a blog site, I have some blog posts in a json file which are fetched inside a useEffect. Eacht blogpost has an id so when I click on one, I can go to a detail page.

To make sure the user can only visit pages with an existing blog post, I want to redirect them if the id from the url does not match any id's available.

At this point, when the user is directed to a page with an existing id, it shows the blog post how it should be. But when I change the id to a number that does not exist in my posts, it stays on the same page but there is no redirecting. Just a white page

I'm breaking my head my code is not running as I wanted it to be.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, please let me know!
Bear in mind I'm still a student with a minimum of react knowledge.

The code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/detail.css'
import PostHero from '../components/design/PostHero/PostHero';
import HistoryButton from '../components/design/HistertButton/HistoryButton';


const Detail = () => {

    // This state stores the specific post we want to show
    const [myData, setData] = useState({}); 
    // This hook allows us to use parameters in our url
    const { id } = useParams()

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    // Wacht op de data van de json en injecteert deze in mijn myData state
    useEffect(() => {
        let isActive = true;
        fetch('../blogs.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (isActive) {
                setData(data.find(post => post.id == id ))
                console.log(myData)
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        })
        return () => isActive = false
    }, [id, setData, setIsLoading]);


    // Controlleert of de loading gebeurd is en de id niet bestaat, indien ja moet je redirected worden
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoading === false && myData.id === undefined) {
            window.location.replace("/not-found");
          }
    }, [myData, isLoading])

    return (
        <div className='blog-detail'>
            {/* This is the hero image of our specific post */}
            <PostHero id={myData.id}/>
            <div className='post-container'>
                <div>
                    <div className='content-header'>
                        <h2 className='post-title'>{myData.titel}</h2>
                            {/* Our button to return back to the homepage */}
                            <HistoryButton />
                    </div>
                    <span className='post-date'>{myData.datum}</span>
                        <ul className='post-tags'>
                            {/* We map through our tags */}
                            {
                                myData.tags && myData.tags.map((tag,index) => (
                                <div className='li-item'>
                                    <div className='li-indicator' style={{backgroundColor: `var(--${tag})`}}/>
                                    <li key={index}>{tag}</li>
                                </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='content-container'>
                    <div className='post-tekst'>
                        {myData.description}
                    </div>
                    <div className='detail-photos'>
                        {/* We map through the other 5 images our post has */}
                        {
                            myData.detail_images && myData.detail_images?.map((img, index) => (
                                <div className='detail-image'>
                                    <img src={`../../../${img}`} alt="card image" key={index}/>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Detail;
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You just need to redirect to `"/not-found"` if there is no JSON data fetched? Can you [edit] to clarify? It might be helpful if you could add `blogs.json` file to the post and an example route path value, and what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll make some changes in my question. A moment please!

Comment: This is not how you redirect in react router dom

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise using `window.location.replace` to redirect as this will reload the page and the React app along with it. I recommend importing the `useNavigate` hook and issuing an imperative redirect from the Promise chain processing the JSON data.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/detail.css'
import PostHero from '../components/design/PostHero/PostHero';
import HistoryButton from '../components/design/HistertButton/HistoryButton';

const Detail = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [myData, setData] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let isActive = true; // * note
    fetch('../blogs.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (isActive) {
          const post = data.find(post => String(post.id) == id);
          if (post) {
            setData(post);
            console.log(post);
          } else {
            navigate("/not-found", { replace });
          }
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });

    return () => {
      isActive = false;
    };
  }, [id, navigate, setData, setIsLoading]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default Detail;
```

****Note:** I left the "isMounted" check in place since this isn't what the post is about, but this has become a React anti-pattern. The current pattern is to use a cancel token on any in-flight `fetch` requests when the component unmounts.*

It may be better to only fetch the JSON data once when the component mounts, and search the posts data for matching post by `id` separately.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/detail.css'
import PostHero from '../components/design/PostHero/PostHero';
import HistoryButton from '../components/design/HistertButton/HistoryButton';

const Detail = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;

    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch('../blogs.json', { signal })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {
        setPosts(posts);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [setPosts, setIsLoading]); // state setters are stable references

  const post = posts.find(post => String(post.id) == id);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  if (!post) {
    return <Navigate to="/not-found" replace />;
   }

  return (
    ...
  );
}

export default Detail;
```

Comment: I will try this out in the afternoon, I'll let you know how it went!

Comment: I tries this code but on valid url's, I also get redirected

Comment: @Stef-Verniers Are you saying that with valid URLs, e.g. valid post `id` route param, that `post` in the code is still falsey and the `Navigate` redirect is still rendered?

Comment: I think so yeah, however, I got it working thanks to my teacher but I thank you for your help